# Tips for speeding up google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am running a selenium web scraper via a google cloud function and iterating through  different rows in a table on the page which contain links. The code runs much faster in between links locally than on google cloud. The slowness does not appear to be due to a slow cold start. None of the suggestions here [Speeding up Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064786/speeding-up-cloud-functions) apply to my scenario. Are there any other reasons why the google cloud function would be much slower ?

Comment: Alternately, is it better to deploy my code somewhere else on gcp where there are longer allowed timeout (completion) periods ?

Comment: If you're looking for a broad set of tips, best practices, or general advice, it would be better if you posted to a discussion board, such as Reddit.

Comment: If you're having a problem with code, please ensure that your question includes the minimal code that allows others to reproduce that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) documentation on the best practices for designing, implementing, testing and deploying Cloud Functions, specially the [performance section](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance). In addition, you should keep in mind that Cloud Functions are not meant for this kind of tasks.

Besides that, seeing your use case, I would not use Cloud Functions for that matter, I would suggest you to set up a Compute Engine instance and run Selenium using `cronjobs` as explained in [this](https://pavelslepenkov.info/?p=979) and [this](https://www.simoahava.com/google-cloud/scrape-domain-and-write-results-to-bigquery/) posts, even though they are not using Selenium specifically. You can also check [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/garywu/google-compute-engine-selenium) in which they are using Selenium inside a Compute Engine instance.